# Addition of two 64 bit numbers in emu8086

Tags: assembly, x86, addition, x86-16

I've searched for about one day but I can't find anything about `adding 64 bit numbers in assembly - emu8086`

How can I do this ?

My registers are only 16 bit and I have 2 numbers of 64 bits. The application I am using it's emu8086. (it's for a school project)

Comment: You basically add them 16 bits at a time, then include the carry bit in the next add, e.g. add ax, bx, adc cx, dx, and so on.

Comment: but how can I split numbers into 16 bit registers?

Comment: Are numbers stored in memory? You can read them, 2bytes by 2bytes.

Comment: It must be something very simple. I just need to declare them and  store the result in another 64 bit number, let's say `sum`. I am very noob at assembly. It's my first time when I try to learn it. ( I made a little application before, but only with compare and jumps for 16 bit numbers )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `adc` to propagate carries between individual 16-bit additions. The following will add number 2 from memory to number 1 in memory:

```
mov ax, [num1_bits0_15]
add ax, [num2_bits0_15]
mov [num1_bits0_15], ax

mov ax, [num1_bits16_31]
adc ax, [num2_bits16_31]
mov [num1_bits16_31], ax

mov ax, [num1_bits32_47]
adc ax, [num2_bits32_47]
mov [num1_bits32_47], ax

mov ax, [num1_bits48_63]
adc ax, [num2_bits48_63]
mov [num1_bits48_63], ax
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Oh, I understand. So in emu8086 I can't use DQ ( to declare a number with 64 bit ) . I just declare it in 4 registers ( 16 bits each )